# pytorch geometric data - split into positive and negative train/test edges using a timestamp

Tags: time-series, autoencoder, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I'm using pytorch geometric. My data is of the class: `torch_geometric.data.Data`. Most tutorials I see use `torch_geometric.utils.train_test_split_edges` (depreciated now, recommended to use `torch_geometric.transforms.random_link_split`. Any way, both of these functions work to split my data. However, my data has a time component and I'd like to do a **train/test split using a date as a threshold**. How can I accomplish this?

My data object looks like:

```
Data(x=[17815, 13], edge_index=[2, 62393], edge_attr=[62393], edge_time=[62393], edge_label=[62393], input_id=[1], batch_size=1)
```

I can get my own `train_mask` and `test_mask` by doing something like:

```
train_mask = (data.edge_time < time_threshold)
test_mask = (data.edge_time >= time_threshold)
```

But again this would take some work to filter all the components of `Data` and it does not have negative edge indices. My model needs positive and negative edge indices just like `torch_geometric.utils.train_test_split_edges` returns.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in theory simply use the node mask to generate a train and test edge_index tensor:

```
edge_index_train = data.edge_index[:, train_mask]
edge_attr_train = data.edge_index[train_mask]
```

and respectively replace `train_mask` with `~train_mask` (or test_mask) for the test dataset.